# New Table Row if var = 0

Tags: php, html-table

I've got the following:

```
<table border="1">
<?php
 $i = 0;
$tmp = 1;
foreach ($recip['Data']['Recipes'] as $key => $recipe) {
        $tmp = $i % 2;
        echo $tmp; 
        if($tmp == 0) {
            echo '<tr>';
        }
        echo '<td>
                  <a href="/recipe_search.php?id=' . $recipe['ID'] . '">';
        echo  $recipe['TITLE'];
        echo '</a> </td>';
        if($tmp == 0){
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        $i = $i + 1;    
 } 
 ?>
</table>
```

What I want is, that, two values are in one row. So if `$tmp` is even, a new row should be started. Unfortunately, the code does not do that, every value stands in a new row. 
How can I manage this?

Comment: you have no idea what is happening in this snippet, right ?

Comment: `echo`ing `$tmp` in the middle of table html is going to make it invalid so how the browser renders it is unpredictable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<table border="1">
<?php
 $i = 0;

foreach ($recip['Data']['Recipes'] as $key => $recipe) {
        if($i % 2 == 0) {
            echo '<tr>';
        }
        echo '<td><a href="/recipe_search.php?id=' . $recipe['ID'] . '">';
        echo  $recipe['TITLE'];
        echo '</a> </td>';
        if(($i+1) % 2 == 0){
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        $i++;    
 } 
 // if there is an odd number of entries, the last one will include only one recipie.
 // but we must still echo </tr>
 if(count($recip['Data']['Recipes']) % 2 != 0){
    echo '</tr>';
 }
 ?>
</table>
```